# Array displaying with InnerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a student and i've been working on a pizza ordering program in javascript and html for school. I get all the information about an order from an array with *document.form.item.value*, from input type="number" name= "*item*" > *item* Pizza .  I then want to display the order.  Currently I'm using this code:

```js
 var showOrder = document.getElementById('screen'); 
 showOrder.innerHTML = '';
 document.getElementById("yourOrder").innerHTML = "<u><b>Your Order: </b></u>";
 document.getElementById("stanPizzaTitle").innerHTML = '<u><b>Standard - $9.95:</b></u>'
 document.getElementById("hawaiianList").innerHTML = 'Hawaiian x ' + stanPizza[0],
 document.getElementById("cheeseList").innerHTML = 'Cheese x ' + stanPizza[1],
 document.getElementById("veggieList").innerHTML = 'Veggie x ' + stanPizza[2],
 document.getElementById("supremeList").innerHTML = 'Supreme x ' + stanPizza[3],
 document.getElementById("pepperoniList").innerHTML = 'Pepperoni x ' + stanPizza[4],
 document.getElementById("gourPizzaTitle").innerHTML = '<u><b>Gourmet: - $15.95</b></u>'
 document.getElementById("meatloversList").innerHTML = 'Meat Lovers x ' + gourPizza[0],
 document.getElementById("chickenList").innerHTML = 'Chicken x ' + gourPizza[1],
 document.getElementById("prawnList").innerHTML = 'Prawn x ' + gourPizza[2];
```

And then displaying it with:

```html
<div id="order"> <!-- division to list all the pizzas ordered -->
    <p id= "yourOrder"></p>
 <p id= "stanPizzaTitle"></p>
 <p id= "hawaiianList"></p>
 <p id= "cheeseList"></p>
 <p id= "veggieList"></p>
 <p id= "supremeList"></p>
 <p id= "pepperoniList"></p>
 <p id= "gourPizzaTitle"></p>
 <p id= "meatloversList"></p>
 <p id= "chickenList"></p>
 <p id= "prawnList"></p>

</div>
```

However, this means that when I want to display the order it shows items that you have ordered zero of, like if you order 0 chicken pizzas then it will needlessly tell you 0 chicken pizzas.  Is there any way that I could make items which have 0 ordered not be displayed using it this way?  Otherwise is there another way I could accomplish this?

Here is the full Program if it helps:

```html
<html>
<title>Pete's Pizzas Ordering Program</title>

<script>

// Title: Pete's Pizzas Ordering Program
// Author: Joel Shepherd - 216032369
// Purpose: Pete's Pizza Ordering program for online customer order
// Verison: 2
// Date Competed:

const stanPizzaCost = 9.50;  // for cost of the standard Pizzas
const gourPizzaCost = 15.50;  // for cost of the gourmet Pizzas+
const delivCharge = 5;   // for cost of delivery
var stanPizzaTotal = 0;
var gourPizzaTotal = 0;

function delivery() {
 delivOption = document.getElementById("delivOption").checked //is the order a delivery or not variable
 return;
 }

function order() {  //the function that controls all the information about the pizzas

 delivery()
 
 var stanPizza =    
 [
  document.form.hawaiian.value,  // allocating standard pizza types in array and converting to a number
  document.form.cheese.value,
  document.form.veggie.value,
  document.form.supreme.value,
  document.form.pepperoni.value;
 ]
 for( i = 0, stanPizzaTotal = 0; i < stanPizza.length; i++) // calculate the total number of standard pizzas
  stanPizzaTotal += stanPizza[i]

 var gourPizza = 
 [ 
  document.form.meatlovers.value,  // allocating gourmet pizza types in array and converting to a number
  document.form.chicken.value, 
  document.form.prawn.value;
 ]
 for( i = 0, gourPizzaTotal = 0; i < gourPizza.length; i++) // calculate the total number of gourmet pizzas
  gourPizzaTotal += gourPizza[i]
 
 var pizzaTotal = stanPizzaTotal + gourPizzaTotal //calculate the total number of pizzas
 
 if(pizzaTotal > 12) {  //checking that they don't order over 12 pizzas
  alert("Sorry but you can only order 12 pizzas, not " + pizzaTotal + "\n(The Page will reload)")
  window.location.reload()
  return;
 }else { 
  
 var showOrder = document.getElementById('screen'); //changing the display to show the order
 showOrder.innerHTML = '';
 document.getElementById("yourOrder").innerHTML = "<u><b>Your Order: </b></u>";
 document.getElementById("stanPizzaTitle").innerHTML = '<u><b>Standard - $9.95:</b></u>'
 document.getElementById("hawaiianList").innerHTML = 'Hawaiian x ' + stanPizza[0],
 document.getElementById("cheeseList").innerHTML = 'Cheese x ' + stanPizza[1],
 document.getElementById("veggieList").innerHTML = 'Veggie x ' + stanPizza[2],
 document.getElementById("supremeList").innerHTML = 'Supreme x ' + stanPizza[3],
 document.getElementById("pepperoniList").innerHTML = 'Pepperoni x ' + stanPizza[4],
 document.getElementById("gourPizzaTitle").innerHTML = '<u><b>Gourmet: - $15.95</b></u>'
 document.getElementById("meatloversList").innerHTML = 'Meat Lovers x ' + gourPizza[0],
 document.getElementById("chickenList").innerHTML = 'Chicken x ' + gourPizza[1],
 document.getElementById("prawnList").innerHTML = 'Prawn x ' + gourPizza[2];
 
 confirm = document.createElement("INPUT");  //button input elements for confirming or canceling the order
    confirm.setAttribute("type", "button");
 confirm.setAttribute("value", "Confirm Order");
    confirm.setAttribute("onClick", "calculate()");
 document.body.append(confirm);
 
 clear = document.createElement("INPUT");
    clear.setAttribute("type", "button");
 clear.setAttribute("value", "Cancel Order");
    clear.setAttribute("onClick", "window.location.reload()");
 document.body.append(clear);
 }

}

function calculate() {  // Function to calculate the total cost for the order

  // adding cost for delivery if checked
 if (delivOption == true) {
 var delivery = 1
 
 details()
 } else {
 var delivery = 0
 details()
 }
 var totalPrice = (stanPizzaTotal * stanPizzaCost) + , //calculate the total price
      (gourPizzaTotal * gourPizzaCost) + ,
      (delivery * delivCharge);
}

function details() {  //function to collect all the details of the customer

 if (delivOption == true) {  //get info for name, phone and address for delivery
 var delivName = prompt("Please enter a name for the Delivery")
 var delivAddress = prompt("Please enter an address for the Delivery")
 var delivPhone = prompt("Please enter a phone number for the Delivery")
 
 var showDetails = document.getElementById('screen','pickUpDetails');
 showDetails.innerHTML = '';
 document.getElementById("yourDetails").innerHTML = "<u><b>Your Delivery Details: </b></u>";
 document.getElementById("delivName").innerHTML = 'Your Name ' + delivName,
 document.getElementById("delivAddress").innerHTML = 'Your Address ' + delivAddress,
 document.getElementById("delivPhone").innerHTML = 'Your Number ' + delivPhone;
 confirm.setAttribute("onClick", "end()"); //change the confirm button to the end() function
 }


 else {  //get name for a pick up
 var pickUpName = prompt("Please enter a name for the Pick-Up")
 var showOrder = document.getElementById('screen','delivDetails');
 showOrder.innerHTML = '';
 document.getElementById("pickUpDetailsTitle").innerHTML = "<u><b>Your Details: </b></u>",
 document.getElementById("pickUpName").innerHTML = 'Your Name ' + pickUpName;
    confirm.setAttribute("onClick", "end()"); //change the confirm button to the end() function
 }
}
function end() { //function to tell the customer that their order has been placed,
 alert("Your order had been placed.")  //and reload ready for the next order
 window.location.reload()
 return;
}

</script>





<div id= "screen">
<body>
<div>
<h1> Welcome to Pete's Pizzas Ordering Program </h1>
<p>Enter the pizzas you would like to order</p>
<form name ="form">  <!-- form to allow text entry to set values of ordering Standard Pizzas -->
<p>Standard Pizzas:</p>
<input type="number" name= "hawaiian" > Hawaiian Pizza<br>
<input type="number" name= "cheese" > Cheese Pizza<br>
<input type="number" name= "veggie" > Veggie Pizza<br>
<input type="number" name= "supreme" > Supreme Pizza<br>
<input type="number" name= "pepperoni" > Pepperoni Pizza<br>

<form name ="form">  <!-- form to allow text entry to set values of ordering Gourmet Pizzas -->
<p>Gourmet Pizzas:</p>
<input type="number" name= "meatlovers" > Meat Lovers Pizza<br>
<input type="number" name= "chicken" > Chicken Pizza<br>
<input type="number" name= "prawn" > Prawn Pizza<br>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" id= "delivOption">
<label for = "delivOption">Is the order a delivery?</label><br>
<br>
<input type="button" value="Order Now" onClick="order()"> <!-- button which triggers the ordering function -->
<input type="button" value="Cancel Order" onClick="window.location.reload()" > <!-- button to cancel the order -->
</div>

</form>
<br> Standard Pizza Cost $9.95<br>
<br> Gourmet Pizza Cost $15.95 </br>
<i> (Note : Maximum 12 Pizzas per Order) </i>
</div>

<div id="order"> <!-- division to list all the pizzas ordered -->
    <p id= "yourOrder"></p>
 <p id= "stanPizzaTitle"></p>
 <p id= "hawaiianList"></p>
 <p id= "cheeseList"></p>
 <p id= "veggieList"></p>
 <p id= "supremeList"></p>
 <p id= "pepperoniList"></p>
 <p id= "gourPizzaTitle"></p>
 <p id= "meatloversList"></p>
 <p id= "chickenList"></p>
 <p id= "prawnList"></p>

</div>
<div id="delivDetails"> <!-- division to list all the info for delivery -->
 <p id= "yourDetails"></p>
 <p id= "delivName"></p>
 <p id= "delivAddress"></p>
 <p id= "delivPhone"></p>
</div>

<div id="pickUpDetails"> <!-- division to list all the info for pick-up -->
 <p id= "pickUpDetailsTitle"></p>
 <p id= "pickUpName"></p>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is a lot of syntax errors here

Comment: Probably I haven't done that much before in javascript and html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the code as follows:

In the order() function, where you set all the innerHTML on the items do the following:

`document.getElementById("hawaiianList").innerHTML = stanPizza[0] > 0 ? 'Hawaiian x ' + stanPizza[0] : ""`

Do that for each of them. It is a conditional, so it will only display the text of the order if the order number is greater than 0.